# Bug in bassistance form validation

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use bassistance form validation plugin

I want to use the code demonstrated in [this demo](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/custom-methods-demo.html).

In the first `textbox`, it shows error until i type 3-digit value, then it shows OK, the bug starts to show when I delete some characters and make it less than 3 digits again, it shows an error message with an *ok* icon

I checked the generated element with firebug and I noticed that it has both `error` and `sucess` css classes, it should have one of them at a time

I tried to modify the success function in the demo source code as follows:

```
success: function(label) {
    label.text("ok!").addClass("success");
    label.removeClass("error");
}
```

But it didn't work. I find this example really powerful and I hope to fix it and use it in my work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Mind throwing this into a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I believe it's the `error` method you should modify, so that it removes the `success` class ;)

Comment: The error is there even in the plugin. It is better to report this error to the developer too!

Comment: Still not working with the last fix

Answer (score 0):

#### Fix for this:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.appendTo( element.parent("td").next("td") );
    element.parent("success").removeClass("success");
},
```

Comment: Will try to meddle. Please wait. @AkramHassan